# Kann man zwei Punkte am Satzende zusammenfassen

Tags: style, punctuation, abbreviation

Wenn ich einen Satz mit einer Abkürzung schließe (etc.) oder z. B. mit einem abgekürzten Firmennamen (Activision Publishing, Inc.), sieht es etwas merkwürdig aus, wenn zwei Punkte hintereinander gesetzt werden:

> ... dieses und jenes etc..

Ist es möglich, diese beiden Punkte zu einem "zusammenzufassen"? Also stattdessen:

> ... dieses und jenes etc.

Und falls es grammatikalisch korrekt ist (oder technisch falsch, aber praktisch überall toleriert wird), welches ist der bessere Stil (in akademischen Kontexten)? Würde der Leser eher denken "Oh, der ist aber penibel, zwei Punkte zu setzen!" oder "Wie aufmerksam von ihm, zwecks besserer Lesbarkeit nur einen Punkt zu setzen!"?

Comment: Eine ausführliche Antwort zum Thema, wann man den Abkürzungspunkt verwendet und wann man ihn wegkürzt, gab es kürzlichst im [Blog von canoo.net](http://canoo.net/blog/2015/03/04/der-standhafte-abkuerzungspunkt/).

Comment: Es wäre sogar falsch zwei Punkte zu machen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wenn eine Abkürzung am Ende eines Satzes steht, setzt man nur einen Punkt.

Das ist nicht nur eine typografische Regel, siehe z. B. DIN 5008

> Der Abkürzungspunkt am Satzende schließt den Satzschlusspunkt mit ein.

sondern auch eine Rechtschreibregel, siehe § 103 des amtlichen Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung

> Am Ende eines Ganzsatzes setzt man nach Abkürzungen nur einen Punkt.

Ebenda findet man auch folgendes anschauliche Beispiel

> Sein Vater ist Regierungsrat a. D.
>
> *Aber:* Ist sein Vater Regierungsrat a. D.?

Comment: Für die explizite Antwort auf die Frage würde ich den Satz ergänzen: "Das kann man nicht nur, sondern muss es  sogar."

Comment: Und um gewissen fällen Doppeldeutig oder Unterbrechungen im Lesefluss zu vermeiden stelle ich dann den Satz um oder was? Nach Abkürzungen setzt man immer nur einen Punkt. Über das Satzende-Zeichen trifft das überhaupt keine Aussage. Die DINorm dagegen versucht quasi vorzuschreiben, die Kreiszahl wäre behelfsweise auch mal äquivalent zu drei. So ein Stuss..